# Display Images In Worksheet With Vba Codes

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to write a VBA code that allows me to click on a cell and make an image appear.

Someone has already done it [video from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ff30DTj6UWk) with this code:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
    Image1.Visible = False
    Range("F1").ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("")
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static OldCell As Range
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Image1_Click
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$" & ActiveCell.Row Then
        Range("F1").Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Image1.Visible = True
        Image1.Top = ActiveCell.Top
        Image1.Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Left
    End If

    On Local Error Resume Next
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & Range("F1").Value & ".jpg")
    If Err Then Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\Yok.jpg")

    If Not OldCell Is Nothing Then
        OldCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$A$" & ActiveCell.Row Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Set OldCell = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

Additionally there is another small piece of code in "this Workbook"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Data").Image1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I've been trying to adapt this code to my sheet but I wasn't able to do it. I got an exercise list on column A and when I click on each exercise I want the relative picture to appear on column I. This exercise list is located on a sheet called Analysis. My pictures are located on my desktop on a folder called Exercises. Pictures are in ".PNG". I don't know if this info is relevant but each exercise (with the list on column A) contains a Vlookup function.

From the code above you can see that the picture appears in line with the cell selected, you can eliminate this by deleting the following piece of code:

```
 Image1.Visible = True
 Image1.Top = ActiveCell.Top
 Image1.Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Left
```

To be honest i would be happy if this code can be adapted to my case, anyway I would prefer the picture to appear on a selected range "I3".

Don't hesitate to contact me for further info.
Thank you

This was my code adapted

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
    Image1.Visible = False
    Range("I1").ClearContents
    Range("A3").Select
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("")
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static OldCell As Range
    If Target.Address = "$A$3" Then
        Image1_Click
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$" & ActiveCell.Row Then
        Range("I1").Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Image1.Visible = True
        Image1.Top = ActiveCell.Top
        Image1.Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Left
    End If

    On Local Error Resume Next
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Exercises\" & Range("I1").Value & ".PNG")
    If Err Then Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Exercises\Yok.PNG")

    If Not OldCell Is Nothing Then
        OldCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$A$" & ActiveCell.Row Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Set OldCell = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

The little one

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Analysis").Range("A3").Select
    Sheets("Analysis").Image1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

When i run the code i got the error "object required" and the code line `Image1.Visible = True` highlighted.

Comment: re: *'... i wasn't able to do it'* Please include the portion of the code you were having trouble with as well as any errors that you received.

Comment: Above you can also find my code. I was able to make only some changes that i thought would be beneficial for my case.

Comment: You do have an Image1 object on your worksheet, right?

Comment: No i don't have Image1 on my worksheet, i don't understand where this Image1 comes from.

Comment: `Image1` is the default name of the first *Image ActiveX Control* on the sheet. You can add them by using the *Insert* option from the Developer Tab.

Comment: Ok i tried again and some piece of code is working (It doesn't bring me all the pictures just some). Indeed i got the error "-2147417848 (80010108)'. It says Method 'Picture' of object 'IImage' failed. I didn't write wrong it says IImage with double I. Additionally it highligths the following line: `Image1.Picture = LoadPicture`